# C++ Keep on getting an expression must have a class type?

Tags: c++

I have a Person class which has a vector of Accounts. The account class is an abstract class and has a class type CurrentAccount. I have a method which will print out a Person account details called 'printAllAccounts'. But I see to be getting an error where it says 'accounts' and it says 'expression must have a class type'. 
Here is the person header class:
Person.h

```
    #include "pch.h"
#include "Account.h"


using namespace std;

class Person {
public:
    Person(string);
    void addAccount(Account &);
    bool closeAccount(int *);
    void printAllAccounts();
    bool creditMoney(int *, double *);
    bool debitMoney(int *, double *);
    virtual ~Person();
private:
    const string name;
    vector<Account> accounts;
};
```

Here is the method for for Person.cpp:

```
void Person::printAllAccounts()
{
    if (accounts.size() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < accounts.size(); i++)
        {
               //below line of accounts is where error is happening
            cout << **accounts**.at(i).printDetails().c_str() << endl;
        }
    }
    else {
        cout << "Person : " << name << " has no accounts" << endl;
    }

}
```

[Edit]
Here is print details in the Account Class:

Actually there is an error on `return toRet;
Account.cpp file`

```
void Account::printDetails() const
{
    ostringstream conAcc, conBal;
    conAcc << this->accountNo;
    string toRet;
    toRet += "Account No: ";
    toRet += conAcc.str();
    toRet += " Balance : ";
    conBal << this->balance;
    toRet += conBal.str();
    return toRet;
}
```

Here is the Account.h header file(abstract class)

```
#include "pch.h"

using namespace std;

class Account {
public:
    Account(int *, double *);
    virtual ~Account();
    bool debit(double *);
    bool credit(double *);
    int getAccNo();

    //making it abstract
    virtual double getBalance() const = 0;
    virtual void printDetails() const;
private:
    double balance;
    int accountNo;
};
```

Comment: What is `printDetails()`, and does it return a `std::string`?

Comment: From the name, it sounds like `printDetails` prints the details rather than returns a string containing the details. (You might be confusing "output" as in "printing to the console" with "output" as in "returning a value from a function".)

Comment: First, include the `Accounts.h` header in your post; it's relevant. If it is as you say it is, *"The account class is an abstract class"*, then you shouldn't have a concrete vector of those anyway, as [you're going to slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing?r=SearchResults&s=1|359.4793). Second, break that line into *at least* two statements to isolate the *real* error. And just fyi, `using namespace std;` = *horrible* thing to put anywhere, *especially* a header file.

Comment: Can you show the declaration of `Account` class? Or at least `printDetails()` method declaration?

Comment: I include Account.cpp and Account.h files

Comment: With your update, that's all kinds of broken. `Account::printDetails` returns `void`, so attempting to reference `c_str()` as a member function is obviously not going to work. That said, I said it earlier and I'll say it again, A vector of concrete `Account` objects **won't work**. See [What is object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing?r=SearchResults&s=1|359.4793) for why.

Comment: Does your Account.cpp compile? You are trying to return an `std::string` from function returning `void`

Comment: @WhozCraig, before slicing you'll get a [compile error](https://godbolt.org/z/aq6fJ-).

Answer (score 2):

`std::vector<Account>` will internally create an array of `Account` and thus cannot store derived classes like `CurrentAccount`. Even if you add a `CurrentAccount` object, the vector will create a copy of type `Account` and store that. And if `Account` is abstract, you won't be able to store anything at all, since an abstract class cannot be instantiated. *(You might want to look up [object slicing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) to read more about what's going on.)*

To fix this, you can use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Account>>`. That way your vector holds pointers of type `Account*`, which can point to derived classes like `CurrentAccount`.

Comment: You won't be able to store `Account`, because it's an abstract class. You'll get a [compile error](https://godbolt.org/z/aq6fJ-) before slicing could happen.